# Function with different behavior depending on amount of input args

Tags: python, function, if-statement, arguments

I want to create a function which will check if it is a correct hour to make an action, but I want it to be flexible and check condition for every pair of args given as an input to function. I wrote some code how it should look like in theory and now I'm trying to figure out how to write this in code.

```
def report_time(greater_than1=0, lower_than1=24, 
                greater_than2=0, lower_than2=24, 
                greater_than3=0, lower_than3=24, 
                ...
                greater_thanN=0, lower_thanN=24):    
    if greater_than1 < datetime.now().hour < lower_than1:
        logger.info('Hour is correct')
        return True

    if greater_than2 < datetime.now().hour < lower_than2:
        logger.info('Hour is correct')
        return True

    if greater_than3 < datetime.now().hour < lower_than3:
        logger.info('Hour is correct')
        return True

    ...

    if greater_thanN < datetime.now().hour < lower_thanN:
        logger.info('Hour is correct')
        return True
```

Examples of usage:

```
foo = report_time(16, 18)
foo = report_time(16, 18, 23, 24)
foo = report_time(16, 18, 23, 24, ..., 3, 5)
```

Comment: to be honest your naming is misleading, why `greater_than1` is on the left while `lower_than1` is on the right?

Comment: Beacuse greater than is lower value, does it really matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at `*args`:

```
def multi_arg_pairs(*args):
    if len(args) % 2 == 1:
        raise ValueError("arguments must be an even number")
    for v1, v2 in zip(args[0::2], args[1::2]):
        print(v1, v2)
        # Do something with your value pairs

multi_arg_pairs(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Outputs:

```
1 2
3 4
```

Comment: instead of redundant checking we can say to user to pass pairs of interval ends like `multi_arg_pairs((1, 2), (3, 4))`, no need to check for length and `zip`, `ValueError` will be raised during unpacking

Comment: Sure, just note that this is not consistent with the question's stated examples of usage.

Comment: we can always provide a better way instead of recommending "just-working" solution so future googlers may choose a better option

Comment: I agree, you are welcome to edit the answer and add the better approach...

Answer (score 2):

A better alternative would be to make the function accept only a pair of parameters and then iterate over all pairs **outside** of the function and check if on any step a `True` was returned:

```
def report_time(greater_than=0, lower_than=24):
    return greater_than < datetime.now().hour < lower_than


start_times = [10, 12, 20]
end_times = [11, 15, 22]

for start, end in zip(start_times, end_times):
    if report_time(start, end):
        logger.info('Hour is correct')
        break
```

This can be shortened using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [`any`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any):

```
valid_times = map(report_time, start_times, end_times)
if any(valid_times):
    logger.info('Hour is correct')
```

Also, as mentioned by @AzatIbrakov in [his comment to another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55298843/function-with-different-behavior-depending-on-amount-of-input-args#comment97327167_55299069), it will be better if you work with tuples. You can use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter) in this case:

```
def within_limits(limits=(0, 24)):
    return limits[0] < datetime.now().hour < limits[1]


time_limits = [(10, 11), (12, 15), (20, 22)]
if any(filter(within_limits, time_limits)):
    logger.info('Hour is correct')
```